# How to setup RSyntaxTextArea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, rsyntaxtextarea

I'm trying to set up the Github open-source package 'RSyntaxTextArea' and am struggling to understand how to do it. Please can I get help?

I've downloaded the zip file from Sourceforge - https://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea/files/latest/download.

Then, I went into my IDE(IntelliJ) and then I went into dependencies to add an external JAR and I selected the downloaded zip file. Then I tried importing the files for use but it's still showing me errors.

Here's a screenshot of the code and the error highlights:
[image]

Any guidance on fixing this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I downloaded the zip file and uploaded that as a jar instead of the .jar file itself. So I looked for the .jar file and found https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fifesoft/rsyntaxtextarea/3.1.1/jar.